# Find td text in HTML table next to a td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the text inside table td next to a td with text "My Metadata".
I am trying to loop through table tds etc. to find this. Is there any very simple way to search text inside td which is next to td with some value?

[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0wtpjpL/1/)

```
<table id="searchTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      My Metadata
    </td>
    <td>
      I want to alert this td text which is next to td which has text My Metadata
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** and **[`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)**

- Using **[`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** selector you can get element which contains certain text.
- Then use **[`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** to get the sibling next to it.

```js
var text = $('#searchTable td:contains(My Metadata)') // get td which contains the text
  .next() // get sibling next to it
  .text(); //  get text content in it

console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="searchTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      My Metadata
    </td>
    <td>
      I want to alert this td text which is next to td which has text My Metadata
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

If you want to select element with exact match then use **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**

```js
var text = $('#searchTable td').filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'My Metadata'; // check trimmed content and filter based on that
  })
  .next() // get sibling next to it
  .text(); // get text content in it

console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="searchTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      My Metadata
    </td>
    <td>
      I want to alert this td text which is next to td which has text My Metadata
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**UPDATE :** If the html content is in variable , then you can do the following.

```js
var content = `<table id="searchTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      My Metadata
    </td>
    <td>
      I want to alert this td text which is next to td which has text My Metadata
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>`;

var text = $(content).find('td:contains(My Metadata)') // get td which contains the text
  .next() // get sibling next to it
  .text(); //  get text content in it

console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How can I find the value considering complete html code is in a variable. How can I search from the variable which has all the html table code.

Comment: @Chandana `$(varibale).find('td:cotains('text')').next()text().`

Comment: I tried but it throws error Object doesn't support property or method 'find'

Comment: @Chandana :  some bugs in your code , https://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/f0wtpjpL/5/

Comment: I used quotes which is a mistake. I realized.

Comment: @Chandana : you can use quotes, either you need to escape or use single inside double or vise versa

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:contains` selector and `next()` as shown.

```
$('#searchTable td:contains("My Metadata")').next().text()
```

`:contains("My Metadata")` selector will select `td` inside `#searchTable` having text `My Metadata` and `.next()` will select it's next node and `.text()` will alert the text inside td.

```js
alert($('#searchTable td:contains("My Metadata")').next('td').text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="searchTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      My Metadata
    </td>
    <td>
      I want to alert this td text which is next to td which has text My Metadata
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to select all the elements that contains specified string as innerText and [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to get the immediate next sibling of the element.

```
$('td:contains("My Metadata")')  // Select `<td>` that contains the passed string
    .next()                      // Get the immediate next sibling
    .text();                     // Get inner text
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/f0wtpjpL/2/)

```js
alert($('td:contains("My Metadata")').next().text().trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="searchTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            My Metadata
        </td>
        <td>
            I want to alert this td text which is next to td which has text My Metadata
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```